# Bootstrap 4 grid empty space due to full-width row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap grid layout with ads, and I needed to add a banners row in it. I found a way to do it by adding a container between ads and the banners inside them with a separate row. But now I have a problem that you can see in the picture.

Is there a way to have the ads positioned better and avoid un-used empty space?

Note1: The columns number is responsible to screen size.

Note2: Banners number in a row is responsible for columns number (with d-none trick)

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>

        <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-3 banner">Banner</div>
                 <div class="col-3 banner">Banner</div>
                 <div class="col-3 banner d-sm-none d-md-block">Banner</div>
                 <div class="col-3 banner d-sm-none d-md-block">Banner</div>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ad">Ad</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As your are using **4 columns** in each row, you need put ad columns in a separate row. Bootstrap grid system works on **12 column** layout. So each row must have columns that sums up to 12. You can have any combination of columns such as **.col-md-4, .col-md-4 and .col-md-4** in one row.

No need to take separate container for ad banners.

Try below code.

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ad banners-->
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 banner">Ad banner</div>
                <div class="col-3 banner">Ad banner</div>
                <div class="col-3 banner">Ad banner</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 ad">Col-1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, I simplified it to make it easier to understand, the layout is a bit more complex and I cannot use separate rows as it will break responsibility. I hoped maybe there is a trick allowing to "justify" content somehow.